# tf_echo is correct, yet no result from lookuptranform

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm using urdf withrviz to do forward kinematics related problem.  My question is can we get the results of tf_echo in a script? Also, I'm looking for suggestions why this problem happened.

I could use

rosrun tf tf_echo /base /tool0

to get the correct result:

At time 1499215724.972

- Translation: [0.410, 0.191, 0.947]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.707, 0.000, -0.000, 0.707]
  in RPY (radian) [1.571, 0.000, 0.000]
  in RPY (degree) [89.997, 0.008, 0.004]

Yet, I couldn't use

(trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('base', 'tool0', rospy.Time(0)), refer to [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29) to get the transform, it would throw an exception.

I also tried

> now = rospy.Time.now()

> listener.waitForTransform("base", "tool0", now, rospy.Duration(10.0))
> tf.Exception: . canTransform returned after 10.0023 timeout was 10.

I chagned 10 here to 0.01, 1, etc. and it always gives similar exception.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265441/tf_echo-is-correct,-yet-no-result-from-lookuptranform/) by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-07-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surajmshanbhag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29417/surajmshanbhag/) on 2017-09-16**:
I am having the exact same issue. using tf2 didnt help. Did you solve it ?

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-10-31**:
Yes actually, I followed the tutorial in TF2 and it solved my question, you get the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a local scope for the buffer which made it fail. In the tutorials its mentioned "*The TransformListener object should be scoped to persist otherwise it's cache will be unable to fill and almost every query will fail*". This fixed the issue.

---

Originally posted by [surajmshanbhag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29417/surajmshanbhag/) with karma: 61 on 2017-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0